# Как задать условие джойна, если условие прописано в самом значении атрибута?

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет! Просьба помочь с решением следующей задачи, возможно кто-то уже сталкивался. Есть таблица А, которую надо сджойнить с таблицей B по атрибуту condition.

Таблица А

```
|status|cond_type|
|------|---------|
|saved |         |
|error |EXIT     |
```

Таблица B

```
|status|condition|
|------|---------|
|saved |IS NULL  |
|error |= 'EXIT' |
```

---

```
select *
from A
join B on A.status = B.status and A.cond_type??
```

(если  само условие в атрибуте?).

Таблица B - будет обновляема, нужно решение универсальное.

Comment: На эту же тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1542764/ms-sql-%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd

Answer (score 0):

Разбиваем задачу на две подзадачи:

1. Составить текст запроса и сохранить его в строку.
2. Запустить запрос из строки.

С первой задачей справитесь, наверное. А вторая вот: [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-dynamic.html)