# MS SQL. Динамическая вставка в неизвестную заранее таблицу из таблицы вертикальной относительно целевой

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

MS SQL. Необходимо динамически собрать запрос на insert по данным из другой таблицы, где данные для вставки хранятся вертикально относительно целевой таблицы — имя поля, значение, ключ целевой таблицы.
На вход имеем имя целевой таблицы и некие параметры выборки, в начале (при объявлении курсора) в хранимке делаем выборку из исходной таблицы.
PIVOT агрегирует данные, поэтому кажется, что его применить сюда с какой-нибудь стороны не получится (разве что переворачивать `@ResultTable`, и начинать как-то с неё...
Вот с чего начал:

```sql
    DECLARE @concatenatedNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';


    DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE
                         (
                             RowNumber INT,
                             Name      NVARCHAR(255)
                         );

    INSERT INTO @ResultTable (RowNumber, Name) -- тут теперь хранятся отсортированные столбцы для INSERT'а
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS RowNumber, name
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('core.Table');

    SELECT @concatenatedNames = STRING_AGG(Name + ' ' + CAST(RowNumber AS NVARCHAR), ',')
    FROM @ResultTable;

            DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)

            SET @SqlStatement = '
INSERT INTO ' + @bindingRuleTableName + '
            (' + @concatenatedNames + ')
VALUES
(';

            DECLARE
                @counter INT = 0,
                @isNew BIT = 0,
                @lastKey NVARCHAR(50),
                @entityTypeId INT,
                @engineEntityId VARCHAR(80),
                @entityId VARCHAR(80),
                @key NVARCHAR(50),
                @fieldName NVARCHAR(50),
                @fieldValue NVARCHAR(50);

            DECLARE infosCursor CURSOR FOR
                SELECT rt.Name, ae.FieldValue, ae.Key -- Key — ключ целевой таблицы,
                    -- по нему понимаем, что уже пора строить стейтмент для следующей строки
                    FROM @ResultTable rt
                    LEFT JOIN core.FieldTypes ft ON ft.Name = rt.Name
                    LEFT JOIN core.EntityInfo ae ON ae.FieldTypeId = ft.Id
                ORDER BY rt.RowNumber;

            OPEN infosCursor
            FETCH NEXT FROM infosCursor
                INTO @entityTypeId, @engineEntityId, @entityId, @key, @fieldName, @fieldValue;

            SET @lastKey = @key;
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN
                    if (@isNew = 1)
                        BEGIN
                            SET @SqlStatement = @SqlStatement +
                                                ', ('
                        END;

                    if (@lastKey <> @key)
                        BEGIN

                            DECLARE @singleUpdateStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

                            SELECT @singleUpdateStatement = STRING_AGG(name, ',')
                            FROM -- Вот тут фантазия заканчивается.

                            SET @SqlStatement = @SqlStatement;

                            SET @lastKey = @key; -- обновили хэш
                            SET @isNew = 1; -- Начали формировать новую строку.
                            SET @counter = @counter + 1; -- строка сформирована
                        END;

                    FETCH NEXT FROM infosCursor
                        INTO @entityTypeId, @engineEntityId, @entityId, @key, @fieldName, @fieldValue;
                END;

            CLOSE infosCursor;
            DEALLOCATE infosCursor;

        EXEC sp_executesql @SqlStatement;
```

Где-то внутри себя ощущаю, что уже `infosCursor` можно объявить перевёрнутым и читать строки, мб ошибаюсь и надо динамически уже сам курсор объявлять? :D

Сам итоговый стейтмент осложняется ещё тем, что в исходной таблице могут оказаться строки не для всех имён столбцов, и их нужно будет забивать null'ами.

Вот попытки переворачивать `@ResultTable`:

```sql
DECLARE @pivot_columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @pivot_columns = @pivot_columns + '[' + CAST(RowNumber as VARCHAR) + '],'
FROM @ResultTable

SET @pivot_columns = LEFT(@pivot_columns, LEN(@pivot_columns) - 1)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempTable;

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    RowNumber INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable (RowNumber, Name)
SELECT RowNumber, Name
FROM @ResultTable

    SET @sql = '
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT RowNumber as RN, Name as Name2
    FROM #TempTable as tt
        INNER JOIN core.fieldTypes ft ON ft.Name = tt.Name2
        LEFT JOIN core.entityInfo ae ON ae.fieldTypeId = ft.Id
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    MAX(Name2)
    FOR RN IN ('' + @pivot_columns + '')
) AS PivotTable
'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Переворачивается превосходно, а вот что с ней делать дальше применительно к задаче: не осиливаю уже...

Хотя бы пните в нужную сторону, пожалуйста.

P.S. Insert с заглушками и миллион апдейтов чур не предлагать

UPD:
Сейчас заметил, что в текущей реализации не хватает ещё идентификатора для строк core.entityInfo, который разграничивал бы записи между разными таблицами, но это уже мелочи.

Comment: А можно какой-то образец данных хотя бы для двух строк выдуманной целевой таблицы? Есть одна идея без курсоров и вот этого всего, но надо проверить, что я правильно понимаю формат хранимых данных

Comment: На вход имеем таблицу вида FieldName, FieldValue, TargetKey, TargetTableName.
Необходимо эти данные разложить в разные таблицы с разной схемой данных.

Н-р:
Исходная таблица, которая является перпендикулярной к целевым, будет подобного вида:
('Data','Data1',1,'core.target1'),
('Name','n1',1,'core.target1'),
('Date','123',1,'core.target1'),
('Data','Data2',2,'core.target1'),
('Name','n2',2,'core.target1'),
('Data','Data3',1,'core.target2'),
('Name','n1',1,'core.target2')

Тогда на выходе:
target1:
(1,'Data1','n1',123)
(2,'Data2','n2',null)

target2:
(1,'n1','Data3')

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста, если нечитаемо. Вобью в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

В общем, сложилось следующее решение:

```sql
    DECLARE @concatenatedNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE
                         (
                             RowNumber INT,
                             Name      NVARCHAR(255)
                         )

    INSERT INTO @ResultTable (RowNumber, Name)
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS RowNumber, name
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName)

    SELECT @concatenatedNames = STRING_AGG(Name, ',')
    FROM @ResultTable

    -- Теперь @ResultTable содержит структуру данных с порядковым номером и именем Name

    DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SqlStatement = '
    INSERT INTO ' + @tableName + '
                (' + @concatenatedNames + ')
    VALUES
    ('

    DECLARE
        @iterations INT = 0,
        @totalColumnsCount INT = 0,
        @rowCounter INT = 0,
        @colCounter INT = 0,
        @currentColNumber INT = 0,
        @lastKeyHash NVARCHAR(50),

        @entityTypeId INT,
        @engineEntityId VARCHAR(80),
        @entityId VARCHAR(80),
        @keyHash NVARCHAR(50),
        @fieldName NVARCHAR(50),
        @fieldValue NVARCHAR(50);

    SELECT @totalColumnsCount = MAX(RowNumber) FROM @ResultTable;

    DECLARE cursorInfos CURSOR FOR
        SELECT EntityTypeId, EngineEntityId, EntityId, KeyHash, ft.Name, FieldValue, rt.RowNumber
        FROM core.EntityBrInfo ae
                 INNER JOIN core.FieldTypes ft ON ae.FieldTypeId = ft.Id
                 LEFT JOIN @ResultTable rt ON ft.Name = rt.Name
        WHERE ae.ProfileId = 1
        ORDER BY ae.KeyHash, rt.RowNumber;

    OPEN cursorInfos
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorInfos
        INTO @entityTypeId, @engineEntityId, @entityId, @keyHash, @fieldName, @fieldValue, @currentColNumber;
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @lastKeyHash = @keyHash;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Iteration: ' + CAST(@iterations AS VARCHAR);
            SET @iterations = @iterations + 1;

            DECLARE @singleUpdateStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
            if (@lastKeyHash <> @keyHash) -- Проверяем, что мы всё ещё в текущей строке
                BEGIN
                    PRINT 'New HASH!'
                    IF (@keyHash is null)
                        BEGIN
                            PRINT 'EMPTY HASH!'
                            BREAK;
                        end
                    SET @lastKeyHash = @keyHash; -- обновили хэш
                    SET @rowCounter = @rowCounter + 1; -- строка сформирована

                    -- TODO Вынести в функцию FillNulls
                    WHILE @totalColumnsCount - @colCounter - 1 > 0
                        BEGIN
                            if (@colCounter > 0)
                                SET @singleUpdateStatement = @singleUpdateStatement + ',';

                            SET @singleUpdateStatement = @singleUpdateStatement + 'null';
                            SET @colCounter = @colCounter + 1;
                        END

                    SET @colCounter = 0;
                    SET @singleUpdateStatement = @singleUpdateStatement + '), (';
                END;

            -- TODO Вынести в функцию FillNulls
            WHILE @currentColNumber - @colCounter - 1 > 0
                BEGIN
                    PRINT 'Current colNum: ' + CAST(@currentColNumber as VARCHAR) + ', written colNum: ' + CAST(@colCounter as VARCHAR)
                    if (@colCounter > 0)
                        SET @singleUpdateStatement = @singleUpdateStatement + ',';

                    SET @singleUpdateStatement = @singleUpdateStatement + 'null';
                    SET @colCounter = @colCounter + 1;
                END

            SET @singleUpdateStatement = @singleUpdateStatement + @fieldValue;
            if (@totalColumnsCount > @currentColNumber)
            SET @singleUpdateStatement = @singleUpdateStatement + ',';
            SET @colCounter = @colCounter + 1;

            SET @SqlStatement = @SqlStatement + @singleUpdateStatement;
            PRINT @SqlStatement;
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursorInfos
                INTO @entityTypeId, @engineEntityId, @entityId, @keyHash, @fieldName, @fieldValue, @currentColNumber
            PRINT 'Fetch status: ' + CAST(@@FETCH_STATUS as NVARCHAR)
        END

    PRINT 'Almost closed cursor: ' + @SqlStatement;
    CLOSE cursorInfos;
    DEALLOCATE cursorInfos;
    PRINT 'After closed cursor: ' + @SqlStatement;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT N'Произошла ошибка: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH

    PRINT 'Before postprocessing: ' + @SqlStatement;
    WHILE @totalColumnsCount - @colCounter > 0
        BEGIN
            if (@colCounter > 0)
                SET @SqlStatement = @SqlStatement + ',';

            SET @SqlStatement = @SqlStatement + 'null';
            SET @colCounter = @colCounter + 1;
        END

    SET @SqlStatement = @SqlStatement + ');';

    PRINT 'After postprocessing: ' + @SqlStatement;
    EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @SqlStatement;
```

Это черновой вариант, понятное дело — буду причёсывать, но в целом оно должно быть живое.

P.S. Натыкал PRINT'ы, т.к. в текущем виде оно почему-то не может выйти из цикла `WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0`, несмотря на то, что условие выхода выполняется (вернее оно выходит, но уже даже ни одного принта после этого не пишет и завершает цикл, ошибок не ловится), но это уже совсем другая история...

Comment: Кстати, решение почти рабочее, есть один какой-то баг в каких-то крайних ситуациях, но пока не добрался до него, поэтому опубликую сюда финальный вид, когда закончу.